# Zend Server CE and BIRT Integration with Javabridge

Tags: java, php, eclipse, zend-framework, birt

I was able to get the Zend Server Java Bridge running and tested it successfully, but I am unable to find any information on how to get the Birt Engine to work with the Zend Server Java Bridge. Has anyone figured out how to get this to work?

i am facing the same issue can locate where to download the birt api to run birt reports

viewtopic.php?f=44&t=9452&p=30950&hilit=birt#p30950

If anybody have an example... please... show me how to do it...
Thank you.

Comment: i am using latest zend version and i am trying to use zend java bridge to run birt reports but cant find zends birt api . i am stuck there . i cannot use tomcat or php javabridge . i need to integrate birt reporting with zend javabridge which is tested working fine . but how to run reports .

Comment: what are you looking for in particular? https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=zend+birt gives me plenty results.

Comment: i am tryin to implement birt reporting in zend framework with zend javabridge .but i am lacking birt api to implement birt reporting .

Comment: http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Platform/birt_report_functions.htm   there is no link to download them

Comment: They have been part of Zend Platform. They are not part of Zend Server CE afaik.

Comment: in the latest version zend ce java bridge are included in the community edition .

Comment: yeah i know that its a medium to interact between java code and php but there is some api needed to call or use it has mentioned here files.zend.com/help/Zend-Platform/birt_report_functions.htm  which i cant find since there is no visible link . :(

Comment: The docs say you should download them from within Zend Platform. You've got Zend Server CE, so there likely is no download link. You can try to grab a copy from http://svn.civicrm.org/civicrm/branches/hrd/CRM/Reports/Zend/

Comment: so how can i run birt reports in zend framework i was able to do so with the help of php java bridge in with tomcat server . so is birt reporting possible with zend server ce .

Comment: The BIRT API is a Java API afaik. So by using [Zend Server's JavaBridge API](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server/zend_java_bridge_-_php_api.htm) you can interface with that [Java BIRT API](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/) from PHP. The Zend_Birt API you are looking for is just a thin wrapper for that. It is not part of Zend Framework but only Zend Platform.

Comment: ok i will look in to the Zend Servers JavaBridge api Thanks .

Comment: do you want me to summarize the comments above and provide as an answer for you to accept? Otherwise, I suggest you just delete the question.

Comment: ya i will accept answer for now until something more helpfull comes along i dont know how to delete a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download the 3.7 runtime you should be able to build a command 
line app that runs the reports. Attached is a simple example. To build 
the class make sure you have the jars from the runtime 
download/reportengine/lib directory in the classpath. Once built you 
should be able to call it the same way as the simple Java app. This 
sample does a platform startup and shutdown which is generally not a 
good idea if you are going to generate a lot of reports. A better 
solution is to wrap the Platform startup and report engine creation in a 
singleton that starts when you server starts up, then use the engine to 
create a new task per request.

```
import java.util.logging.Level;

import org.eclipse.birt.core.framework.Platform;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EXCELRenderOption;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineConfig;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineConstants;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.HTMLRenderOption;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.HTMLServerImageHandler;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.IReportEngine;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.IReportEngineFactory;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.IReportRunnable;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.IRunAndRenderTask;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.PDFRenderOption;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.RenderOption;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask;
import org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.script.IReportContext;


public class RunAndRenderTaskTest {

public void runReport() throws EngineException
{

RunAndRenderTask task=null;
IReportEngine engine=null;
EngineConfig config = null;

try{
config = new EngineConfig( );   
//config.setLogConfig("c:/dwn", Level.SEVERE);
//config.setResourcePath("C:/work/workspaces/3.7.1workspaces/BIRT 
Metal/APIs/resources");
Platform.startup( config );

IReportEngineFactory factory = (IReportEngineFactory) Platform
.createFactoryObject( 
IReportEngineFactory.EXTENSION_REPORT_ENGINE_FACTORY );
engine = factory.createReportEngine( config );


IReportRunnable design = null;
//Open the report design

design = engine.openReportDesign("Reports/testlibrary.rptdesign");
task = (RunAndRenderTask) engine.createRunAndRenderTask(design);    
IReportContext irc = task.getReportContext();
//task.setParameterValue("Top Count", (new Integer(5)));
//task.validateParameters();


//HTMLRenderOption options = new HTMLRenderOption();    
//options.setImageDirectory("./");
//options.setOutputFileName("output/resample/external.html");
//options.setOutputFormat("html");
//options.setEmbeddable(false);
//options.setEnableMetadata(true);
//options.setEnableInlineStyle(false);
//options.setEnableAgentStyleEngine(true);
//options.setEnableCompactMode(true);

//PDFRenderOption options = new PDFRenderOption();
//options.setOutputFileName("output/resample/hidefooter.pdf");
//options.setSupportedImageFormats("PNG;GIF;JPG;BMP;SWF;SVG");
//options.setOutputFormat("pdf");

//EXCELRenderOption options = new EXCELRenderOption();  
//options.setOutputFormat("xls");
//options.setOutputFileName("output/resample/customers.xls");
//options.setWrappingText(true);

HTMLRenderOption options = new HTMLRenderOption();
//options.setImageHandler(new HTMLServerImageHandler());
options.setSupportedImageFormats("JPG;PNG;BMP;SVG;GIF");
options.setOutputFileName("output/resample/testlibrary.html");
options.setOutputFormat("html");
//options.setOutputFormat("ppt");



task.setRenderOption(options);
task.run();

irc = task.getReportContext();

task.close();
engine.destroy();
}catch( Exception ex){
ex.printStackTrace();
}   
Platform.shutdown( );
System.out.println("Finished");



}   


/**
* @param args
*/
public static void main(String[] args) {
try
{

RunAndRenderTaskTest ex = new RunAndRenderTaskTest( );
ex.runReport();

System.exit(0);

}
catch ( Exception e )
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i have found some info on integrating birt on zend platform u can also refer this pdf file

http://static.zend.com/topics/Zend-Platform-User-Guide-v360-new.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The `Zend_Birt` is not part of Zend Framework but only of Zend Platform. It is not part of Zend Server CE afaik. However, the [BIRT API is a Java API](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/). So by using [Zend Server's JavaBridge API](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server/zend_java_bridge_-_php_api.htm) you can interface with the BIRT API from PHP. The `Zend_Birt` API you are looking for is just a thin wrapper for that. You can try to grab a copy from

- http://svn.civicrm.org/civicrm/branches/hrd/CRM/Reports/Zend

There is also a [detailed blogpost explaining how to use BIRT reporting without Zend Platform](http://wap.ecw.de/archives/273) via a [JavaBride](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/). It apparently hooks directly into the BIRT runtime environment.